# Git - Find which commits are local

Tags: git, version-control, commit, git-commit, git-log

**How do I know which of local commits are not in remote?**

By, `git log` I see commit history, but I want to find if the last commit is already pushed into server or just a local one. Is there any way to know that without going to server and matching with local history?

Comment: Does `git status` help? _Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a clue,

**`git status`**

```
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Git status also shows the number of commits your current branch ahead from remote.

Thanks to @Danh for comment

Answer (score 2):

Copy the last commit hash, and see the list of branch(es) exists the commit.
If you see the `remote/origin/<branch-name>` then you have pushed the `last commit`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git log                                    # copy last commit-hash
$ git branch -a --contains <last-commit-hash>

# Or, (skip copying commit-hash)
$ git fetch && git branch -a --contains $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD)
```

Comment: You can just calculate this instead of copying it: `git fetch && git branch -a --contains $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check by `git log origin/master..master`.

If there has output, then the showing log is which you didn’t push to remote. If there is no output, that means your current branch is same as master.

**Note:** if the git remote also used by others, you’d better fetch from origin and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

Git has a number of shortcuts, for example **HEAD** refers to the tip of the current branch, while **@{upstream}** refers to the head of remote branch (or the last pushed commit).  These shortcuts are invaluable for using in aliases for example, so you aren't locked into using branch names like *master* and fixed remote names like *origin*.

Using git log;

`git log @{upstream}..HEAD`

I use the following

`git config alias.changes "log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --pretty=terse @{upstream}...HEAD"`

I then simply use

`git changes`

to list the un-pushed changes in my current branch.

**Note**: if *@{upstream}* doesn't seem to work, pay attention to the `-u` or `--set-upstream` option in `git push`. Using `git push -u origin master` will ensure that *origin/master* is considered the upstream repository for branch *master*.  Then the *@{upstream}* shortcuts should work properly.